# Polymer 1.0 Child-to-host one way data binding - readOnly properties

Tags: data-binding, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.0, I would like to have a one way data binding from the child element to the host. You can do this if you define `notify: true` and `readOnly: true` when defining the property.Explained [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html).

Also see my sample below.

Child:

```
...
Polymer({
  is: "child-element",
    properties:{
       myProp:{
         type: Number,
         notify: true,
         readOnly: true,
         value: 0
        }
    }
});
```

Host:

```
...
<child-element my-prop="{{hostValue}}"></child-element>
...
```

Since there are `{{ ... }}` and the property is set to `notify: true` the host will try two-way binding but the child has `readOnly: true`. So the binding will work only child-to-host.

In my setup I want to change the value in the child. So the bound value in the host will change accordingly. But since the property is marked `readOnly: true` also the child cannot change the value.

Is there a way to bind one way from child-to-host, prevent the host to overwrite the value but allow the child to do so?

UPDATE: I prepared a Plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dFKdxHdCA9xgl1oDiQG6). Go to child-element.html. You see the value of the `myProp` is `'Initial value'`. When you click the button nothing happens, because it is set to `readOnly`. But if you comment out that `readOnly` on *line 19* and then click the button, you will see the value changes. So readOnly also prevents to over write the value from with in the child element.

Comment: Did you try changing the value in the child. I think readOnly is only for observers that polymer provides out of the box. You should be able to change the value in the child within child functions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting. But a value set to readOnly does not change, even if you try it from with in the child. I prepared a Plunk and added the link in the original question above. You can see it in action there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use _setMyProp(newValue) to change the read only values within the child-element. You can read more about it in https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#read-only

Updated plunk http://embed.plnkr.co/ggYJQ4z65Wj4uuBe4kUg/preview